# Save Users Info after authenticating with Google Oauth 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

When using Google Oauth 2.0 for authentication, what is the proper method to SAVING the users info (first name, lastname, email, gender, etc) to use in other places and save in the database. With the below code, we keep getting these errors:

1) Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not....

2) Google/Service/Resource.php(208): Google_Auth_OAuth2 >sign(Object(Google_Http_Request))

3) Google/Service/Oauth2.php(153): Google_Service_Resource->call('get', Array, 'Google_Service_...')

4) file_name.php(54): Google_Service_Oauth2_Userinfo_Resource->get()

**Really need some help, we are launching our update this Sunday**

We are using the Google OAuth 2.0 code from this site
     https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

```
//include google api files
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

//start session
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  $client->revokeToken();   //added
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); //redirect user back to page
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
  {
    //For logged in user, get details from google using access token
    $user           = $service->userinfo->get();
    $user_id            = $user['id'];
    $user_name          = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $first_name         = filter_var($user['given_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $last_name          = filter_var($user['family_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $email          = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $profile_url        = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $profile_image_url      = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $gender         = filter_var($user['gender'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $personMarkup       = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'></div>";
    $_SESSION['upload_token']   = $client->getAccessToken();
  }

else
  {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  }
?>
```

Comment: you need to add $client->setAccessType('offline');   if you want to see the refreshtoken.

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot to set it to offline in the Config.php, but is it necessary to set it in the above code as well?

Comment: that would probably depend upon what you are using the config.php for.   $client->setAccessType('offline');  adds something to the request string in in the call in the php client library.

Comment: the only mod done to the Config.php is i set the HD= to a certain domain. I changed the accesstype to offline from online in it, and I add the new line you mentioned in the code above. Lets see if it fixes the problem, I can only test this every 1 hour because thats when the token expires, do you know how I can set the token to expire in like 1 minute so I can test things faster?

Comment: you cant change the timeout.

Comment: So after an hour, it still gives me those same errors, is there anything else you can recommend? Thanks.

Comment: Please help, the line you asked me to put in didnt work.